# Java Socket call SetTrafficClass after Socket has connected

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

After I create a Socket (within Android) I call setTrafficClass to modify the TOS field, then do the rest of the setup and call connect on the Socket and this all works fine.

If I then call SetTrafficClass again the Socket appears to stop working, is this normal behaviour?

Comment: No, but define 'stop working', and tell us what you set the traffic class to.

Comment: @EJP I am setting the value to be between 0-63 and by stop working I mean after connecting the socket I start sending from the client and receive packets on the server side, if I then call setTrafficClass again and change the TOS value the server stops receiving packets.

Comment: @SuperAaz, i wanted to know whether you can actually see the traffic class being modified if you inspect the packets through wireshark ? I am doing the same thing but unfortunately if i see the packets, the TOS value is not modified. I am using android emulator.